# WP Как проверить есть ли хоть одна метка с записью?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как в WordPress сделать проверку есть ли в базе хоть одна метка с записью, и если да, то получить id значение данной метки ?

Comment: Возможно я не совсем понял что вам нужно, но по идее `$terms = get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'fields' =>'ids'] );`, будут возвращены id, только тех меток, у которых есть записи.

Answer (score 0):

В функции get_terms() используйте атрибут [hide_empty](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms#hide_empty) = true ( скрывать пустые)

```
$terms = get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'fields' =>'ids', 'hide_empty'    => true ] );
```

Comment: Он по умолчанию true)